# Solving PDE $\rho_t + v \rho_x + k\rho = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I was hoping for some guidance on solving this PDE. I have taken the rho and fund the partial derivative wrt $t$ and $x$ and have plugged this into the general equation. I am unsure how to proceed from this point with the given initial conditions. Could someone provide me with a hint please?

My thought process is the partial derivative of rho wrt $t$ and $x$ at $t=0$ is 0 and hence I am left with $ke^{-x^2/2} = 0$ and hence $k = 0$. This would make my equation simplify to $$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x} = 0$$.

> Write 
>   $$\rho(x,t) = e^{\frac{-kx}{v}}w(x,t).$$
>   Use this form to solve the PDE problem
>   $$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + v \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x} + k\rho = 0 \quad\quad x\in \mathbb {R} ,t>0, $$
>   $$\rho(x,t=0) = e^\frac{-x^2}{2} \quad\quad x \in \mathbb {R.}$$

Comment: Did you compute $\rho_{t}, \rho_{x}$ using the relation $\rho = \exp(-kx/v) w$ and substitute it into the PDE in $\rho$?

Comment: Yes and I got $$w_t e^{\frac{-kx}{v}} + w_x ve^{\frac{-kx}{v}} - kwe^{\frac{-kx}{v}}+ ke^{\frac{-kx}{v}} = 0$$ From this point I was unsure where to go. What I did do is assume the above procedure, that $\rho_t$ and $\rho_x$ are 0 at the, initial condition t = 0. This means I am left with $Ke^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} = 0$ and hence $k = 0$ This makes my PDE simplify to: $$w_t e^{\frac{-kx}{v}} + w_x ve^{\frac{-kx}{v}} = 0$$ which I recognise as the transport equation with general solution $\rho(x-vt)$

Comment: You've differentiated incorrectly. It isn't possible for there to be a term with no $w$ in it, and your last term only has $k e^{-kx/v}$.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot the $w$. Changing this leads me to $$w_t e^{\frac{-kx}{v}} + w_x ve^{\frac{-kx}{v}} - kwe^{\frac{-kx}{v}}+ kwe^{\frac{-kx}{v}} = 0$$

Comment: Yes, and the last two terms cancel eachother, which is how Harry49 got his first equation in the answer below.

Comment: How did Harry49 get: $w(x,t) = w_0(x-vt) = e^\frac{k(x-vt)}{v} e^\frac{-(x-vt)^2}{2}$ I am unsure where the $x^2$ term arises from as I thought the general solution for $w$ was $w(x-vt)$?

Comment: It comes from applying the initial condition. Why don't you try solving the PDE in $w$ above and append the information to your post.

Comment: @mattos Thank you, given the added explanation given by Harry49 below I have solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your patience and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Ansatz on $\rho$ leads to
$$
\rho_t = e^{-kx/v} w_t
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\rho_x = e^{-kx/v} w_x - \tfrac{k}{v} e^{-kx/v} w \, .
$$
Injecting this into the PDE, the linear transport equation (a.k.a linear advection equation)
$
w_t + v w_x =0
$
satisfied by $w = e^{kx/v} \rho$ is obtained. The solution to the initial-value problem
$$
w(x,0) = e^{kx/v} e^{-x^2/2} = w_0(x)
$$
can be obtained by using the method of characteristics (see e.g. this [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example)):
$$
w(x,t) = w_0(x-vt) = e^{k(x-vt)/v} e^{-(x-vt)^2/2} .
$$
Finally, we know $\rho = e^{-kx/v} w$, i.e.
$$
\rho(x,t) = e^{-kt} e^{-(x-vt)^2/2} .
$$
Note that the method of characteristics can be applied directly to the initial PDE, without introducing $w$ (see e.g. this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3273118/418542)).

Comment: I have come across the general solution to this equation but I do not quite follow what you are saying. I am given ρ and asked to use this to solve the PDE. Could you lay out your thinking please?

Comment: Thank you for this expanded explanation as it has proved very hepful. I have managed to work through and solve the problem now. Many thanks